# How to convert such sql query to mongodb query

Tags: java, sql, mongodb

I need to execute such sql query on mongo(I mean mongodb query should be logically equal to the sql). So here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ALIAS1
WHERE 
 field1=1
AND
 field2=2
AND (
  EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM table2 
    where table2.field33 = ALIAS1.field1
  )
)
```

Is it possible to do such a query in mongodb in one query?

Answer (score 2):

Use https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera for any such sql like queries. it allows a way to execute JPA queries over mongoDB

Comment: Does it really will be converted to one mongoDb query ?